# Uploaded app shows in wrong api level device

Tags: android, api, android-market-filtering, android-sdk-1.6

We have uploaded an app into market with following api level in AndroidManifest file

```
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16"
```

It is for support of api level 4.1.1 and 4.1.2. But this app can be installed on 4.2 which has api level 17. Any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`targetSdkVersion` does not specify the max SDK API level. Use `maxSdkVersion` as well.

[This link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> android:maxSdkVersion="16"   :- This is the maximum SDK version number that an 
>    application works on. [integer]